# How to send mms in blackberry cascade blackberry 10

Tags: blackberry-10, blackberry-cascades

Can you please tell me how to send mms in blackberry cascade c++ .
I have successfully figured out how to send sms and  am able to so but now I am interested to send mms (having  image) but am not able to do that .

Can you please provide me some sample code or example how to send mms in blackberry 10 (cascade)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Programatically sending an MMS is not possible at this time.